# Design APIs for three a combination of dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

I have three dropdownlists. Each of them has a value of "ALL". HTML code is like this:

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="all" selected>All</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="lemon">lemon</option>
</select>

<select id="color">
    <option value="all" selected>All</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>



 <select id="flavor">
        <option value="all" selected>All</option>
        <option value="sweet">Sweet</option>
        <option value="acid">Acid</option>
</select>
```

I want to call APIs based on the user selection of these three dropdownlists. 
I'm designing the APIs and wondering what the parameters should look like.

I'm using ASP.NET API as backend so a API is something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData(string fruitname, string colortype, string flavortype)
{
     var res = db.myclass.Where(z => z.FruitName.Equals(fruitname) 
                    && z.ColorType.Equals(colortype) 
                    && z.FlavorType.Equals(flavortype)).ToList();
     return Ok(res);
}
```

However, once a user selects "ALL", I have to bypass that selection - say if a user selects all in fruit dropdown, I only need to have two conditions in LINQ.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData(string fruitname, string colortype, string flavortype)
{
     var res = db.myclass.Where(z => && z.ColorType.Equals(colortype) 
                    && z.FlavorType.Equals(flavortype)).ToList();
     return Ok(res);
}
```

As there are three dropdownlist here and I don't want to repeat myself again and again. Any good thoughts on how to design these APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `.ToList()` as part of the 'queryable' definition -- wait until you have conditionally decided which `WHERE` filters you want based on conditions.

Something like:

```
var query = db.myclass

if (fruitname != "All")
    query.Where(z => z.FruitName.Equals(fruitname));

if (colortype != "All")
    query.Where( z => z.ColorType.Equals(colortype));

if (flavortype != "All")
    query.Where( z => z.FlavorType.Equals(flavortype));

// query does not get executed until we call .ToList()
var res = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I put the code there and choose lemon, yellow, and sweet I still get all the data from db.myclass....